# Google App Engine: Routing which appends .html

Tags: reactjs, google-app-engine, routes, app.yaml

I'm deploying a React app to Google App Engine. Currently I need to append `.html` or `/index.html` to the requests but I would like to avoid this so I have clean routes.

For example, I can load `mywebsite.com/docs/page1.html` and `mywebsite.com/docs/page1/index.html` but I want to load `mywebsite.com/docs/page1`.  The react app actually builds both of these duplicate pages so it appears this is somewhat default behaviour. The routing is only "broken" like this when I build, it works fine in the dev server.

#### Directory structure

```
- build/my_docs/
  - css/
  - img/
  - js/
  - docs/
    - page1.html
    - page1/
      - index.html
```

#### app.yaml

```
runtime: python3
service: docs

handlers:
  - url: /
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_files: build/my_docs/index.html
    upload: build/my_docs/index.html
  - url: /css/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/css/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/css/(.*)
  - url: /img/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/img/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/img/(.*)
  - url: /js/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/s/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/js/(.*)
  - url: /(.*\.(json|ico|xml))$
    static_files: build/my_docs/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/.*\.(json|ico|xml)$
  - url: /docs/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/docs/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/docs/(.*).html
    # Trying to append .html to non css/img/js requests but it doesn't work!
```

I also tried to deploy the sample [Docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/) project to GAE with no app.yaml handlers, and I see the same undesired routing (need to append `.html`).

Answer (score 0):

Are you satisfied with serving these html files as static docs, or should they be templates which you can pass content to?

First, in your `/` handler, there is no such file `build/my_docs/index.html`

Your `/docs/(.*)` handler appears to be fine.  You say it works in dev but not in build?  That sounds like a routing problem inside React. Check your React routing.  Also, make sure you're resetting your browser cache frequently, as you may be caching old React code.

** EDIT **

Let's look at this handler:

```
- url: /docs/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/docs/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/docs/(.*).html
```

If you request at the url `/docs/page1`, it is going to try to load the static file from the directory `build/my_docs/docs/page1`.  So far, so good, as that directory exists.

The problem comes in the next line.  You are asking to serve the static file `build/my_docs/docs/page1.html`, which does not exist in the directory specified.  Try one of these:

```
 - url: /docs/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/docs/\1
    upload: build/my_docs/docs/(.*)/index.html
```

or:

```
 - url: /docs/(.*)
    static_files: build/my_docs/docs
    upload: build/my_docs/docs/(.*).html
```

I other words, there is a mismatch between the `static_files` directory you specify and the location of the file you're trying to serve.

Comment: They're generated so I don't need to pass content, just serve the file. CSS and JS gets imported in the file. Also there is a `build/my_docs/index.html`, and it's the only route which works properly.

Comment: I didn't mean the route.  I meant the file.  `build/my_docs/index.html` is not in your directory tree, yet you ask for it in your `/` handler.  See Edit